# Permission issue trying to export Picture to AD

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, user-profile-service, my-site, user-profile-property

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm. I am trying to set the property for picture to export to AD.

I have set everything as described in this blog:
http://blog.areflyen.no/2012/06/05/exporting-profile-pictures-from-sharepoint-2010-to-active-directory/

.. but the pictures are not exported to AD. I try to inspect with miisclient, and get a permission-issue

[image]

I have even tried to give full access to the profile sync account, and still get the same issue.

Any ideas what this could be ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the guide from Spence Harbar. Near the end he details the permissions required and the details of how to set the permissions currently. http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

> Do this via ADSIEdit.msc by connecting this time to the default naming context of your domain, selecting properties on the OU you are syncing with, and adding the Create Child Objects and Write permissions to the DOMAIN\spups account.

Then be sure it applies to the **OU and all child objects**. This is all detailed in his article.